# Python parsing complex text

Tags: python, xml-parsing, python-2.6

I'm struggling to develop an algorithm that can edit the below snip of an XML file.  Can anyone help with ideas?  Requirements are to parse the file as input, remove the "cipher" that uses "RC4", and output a new xml file, with just "RC4" cipher removed.  The problem is there are multiple "Connector" sections within the XML file.  I need to read all of them, but only edit the one that uses port 443 and with a specific IP address.  So the script would need to parse each Connector section one at a time, but discard the ones that don't have correct IP address and port.  Have tried:
1.  Using ElementTree XML parser.  Problem is it doesn't output the new XLM file well - it's a mess.  I need it prettified with python 2.6.

```
<Connector
protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
port="443"
redirectPort="443"
executor="tomcatThreadPool"
disableUploadTimeout="true"
SSLEnabled="true"
scheme="https"
secure="true"
clientAuth="false"
sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
keystoreType="JKS"
keystoreFile="tomcat.keystore"
keystorePass="XXXXX"
server="XXXX"
ciphers="TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
         TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
         TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
         TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
         TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
         TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
         TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
         TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
         TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA"
address="192.168.10.6">
```

Here was my code:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
print "[+] Checking for removal of RC4 ciphers"
file = "template.xml"

with open(file, 'rt') as f:
    tree = ElementTree.parse(f)
f.close()

for node in tree.getiterator('Connector'):
    if node.tag == 'Connector':

        address = node.attrib.get('address')
        port = node.attrib.get('port')
        if "EMSNodeMgmtIp" in address and port == "443":
            ciphers = node.attrib.get('ciphers')
            if "RC4" in ciphers:
                # If true, RC4 is enabled somewhere in the cipher suite 
                print "[+] Found RC4 enabled ciphers"

                # Find RC4 specific cipher suite string, for replacement
                elements = ciphers.split()
                search_str = ""
                for element in elements:
                    if "RC4" in element:
                        search_str = element
                        print "[+] Search removal RC4 string: %s" % search_str

                # Replace string by removing RC4 cipher
                print "[+] Removing RC4 cipher"
                replace_str = ciphers.replace(search_str,"")
                rstrip_str = replace_str.rstrip()
                if rstrip_str.endswith(','):
                    new_cipher_str = rstrip_str[:-1]
                    #print new_cipher_str

            node.set('ciphers', new_cipher_str)
tree.write('new.xml')
```

Comment: **what have you tried so far**?  (show. your. code.)

Comment: This is what I had with xml parser, but it did not output the same XML file:

Comment: You still haven't shown any of your python code...

Answer (score 1):

I included comments to explain what is going on.
inb4downvote

```
from lxml import etree
import re

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
<Connector
protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
port="443"
redirectPort="443"
executor="tomcatThreadPool"
disableUploadTimeout="true"
SSLEnabled="true"
scheme="https"
secure="true"
clientAuth="false"
sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
keystoreType="JKS"
keystoreFile="tomcat.keystore"
keystorePass="XXXXX"
server="XXXX"
ciphers="TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
         TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
         TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
         TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
         TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
         TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
         TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
         TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
         TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA"
address="192.168.10.6"></Connector></data>'''

tree = etree.fromstring(xml)
root = tree.getroottree().getroot()
for connector in root.findall('Connector'):
    port = connector.get('port')
    ip = connector.get('address')
    #change this to port/ip you want to remove
    if port != '443' or ip != '192.168.10.6':
        #removes child connector
        connector.getparent().remove(connector)
        continue
    #here we use list comprehension to remove any cipher with "RC4"
    ciphers = ','.join([x for x in re.split(r',\s*', connector.get('ciphers')) if 'RC4' not in x])
    #set the modified cipher back
    connector.set('ciphers', ciphers)
print etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True)
```

Comment: Cody, thanks for the response.  Based on my reading lxml is perfectly what I needed to pretty print xml output.  However, with my version of Python (2.6), it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

If the XML tools don't preserve the original structure and formatting, dump them.  This is a straightforward text-processing problem, and you can write a Python program to handle it.

Spin through the lines of the file; simply echo to the output anything other than a "cipher" statement.  When you hit one of those:

1. Stuff the string into a variable.
2. Split the string into a list.
3. Drop any list element containing "*RC4*".
4. Print the resulting "cipher" statement in your desired format.
5. Return to normal "read-and-echo" processing.

Does this algorithm get you going?

Comment: Dump it (xml parser) - exactly.  I was thinking this way over-complicated and just regular text parsing should work.  Exactly the algorithm to get me going!  Thanks!  I suppose I also need to check to see if the Connector has the correct IP address and port.  There are multiple "Connectors".  If it isn't just output/echo the output as "read-and-echo" processing.  Will give this a run!  Thanks again.  I was drawing a blank on the algorithm.

Comment: So this algorithm will work just fine, but it doesn't take into account checking a "Connector" if it has the correct IP address and port before making the change.  Any suggestions?  If I read through one line at a time, I need to first check to see if the Connector has the correct IP address and port.  Otherwise, I'll be making changes to all of the Connector ciphers.  The xml file has 4 different Connector blocks in it.  Need to only edit one of them.

Comment: Then before you switch from "echo" mode to "change" mode, you need to set a flag: is the most recent Connector the one you want?

Comment: Yes, that is the one I want.  The 'address' and 'port' need to be checked.

Answer (score 0):

Answer below.  Basically had to read each of the Connector sections (there were 4) into a temporary list, to check if port and address are correct.  If they are, then make a change to the Cipher by removing cipher string but only if RC4 cipher is enabled.  So the code had to read in all of the 4 Connectors, one at a time, into a temporary list.

```
f = open('template.xml', 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()

new_file = open('new.xml', 'w')

tmp_list = []
connector = False
for line in lines:
    if '<Connector' in line:
        connector = True
        new_file.write(line)
    elif '</Connector>' in line:
        connector = False
        port = False
        address = False
        for a in tmp_list:
            if 'port="443"' in a:
                port = True
            elif 'address="%(EMSNodeMgmtIp)s"' in a:
                address = True
        if port and address:
            new_list = []
            count = 0
            for b in tmp_list:
                if "RC4" in b:
                    print "[+] Found RC4 cipher suite string at line index %d:  %s" % (count,b) 
                    print "[+] Removing RC4 cipher string from available cipher suites"
                    # check if RC4 cipher string ends with "
                    check = b[:-1]
                    if check.endswith('"'):
                        tmp_str = tmp_list[count-1]
                        tmp_str2 = tmp_str[:-2]
                        tmp_str2+='"\n'
                        new_list[count-1] = tmp_str2
                        replace_line = b.replace(b,"")
                        new_list.append(replace_line)
                    else:
                        replace_line = b.replace(b,"")
                        new_list.append(replace_line)
                else:
                    new_list.append(b)
                count+=1
            for c in new_list:
                new_file.write(c) 
            new_file.write('    </Connector>\n')
        else:
            # Not port and address
            for d in tmp_list:
                new_file.write(d)
            new_file.write('    </Connector>\n')
        tmp_list = []
    elif connector:
        tmp_list.append(line)
    else:
        new_file.write(line)
new_file.close()
```